# Can't use len() on map()

Tags: python

```
c = input("Enter a list of number seperate by ','\n")
d = map(int, c.split(","))

print(sum(d)/len(d))
```

The interpreter says object of type map not have length. How can I know how many number an user enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the `map` object to a `list`, since `map` is like a generator, yielding values *only as needed*

```
c = input("Enter a list of number seperate by ','\n")
d = list(map(int, c.split(",")))
print(sum(d)/len(d))
```

Or, probably more readable, use a list comprehension:

```
c = input("Enter a list of number seperate by ','\n")
d = [int(x) for x in c.split(",")]
print(sum(d)/len(d))
```

---

Alternately you could restructure the code a little bit, since `str.split()` does give you a list:

```
c = input("Enter a list of number seperate by ','\n").split(',')  # <-- split here
d = map(int, c)
print(sum(d)/len(c))  # <-- len(c) instead of len(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using *python3*, where `map` does not return a `list` anymore but a `map` object. 
Convert it to a list explicitly using `list(map(...`